# Why does kotlin not allow null-safe indexing operator?

Tags: kotlin

We are used to the indexing operator when accessing Maps.

```
fun fun1(map: Map<*, *>) {
    assert(map.get("key") === map["key"])
}
```

But why can the indexing operator not be used for nullable Map?
The following code does not compile.

```
fun fun2(map: Map<*, *>?) {
    assert(map?.get("key") === map?["key"])
}
                                  ^^^
```

Comment: I suppose because the syntax of the [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) is `?.` and not `?`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does kotlin not allow null-safe indexing operator?

The reason you can not use `map?.[K]` is because that is not supported syntax. This is a long-standing feature request. Here is a 4 year old issue for it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8799

Use the equivalent method syntax instead, which is `map.get(T)` instead of `map[T]`, i.e. what you have first:

```
fun fun2(map: Map<*, *>?) {
    assert(map?.get("key") === map?.get("key"))
}
```

you can find in the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed) that `.get()` is what implements the `[]` operator. In other words, the compiler translates `[]` into `.get()` behind the scenes, so you might as well call it directly in this case.

Comment: I believe the OP already knows this. The question is _why_ you can't use the null safe operator with `[]`.

Comment: Well, what more can you say than "the syntax is not supported"? Clearly it is theoretically possible to support, it just isn't. I added a note about this in my answer now. I still think my answer gives some non-obvious insights, such as that my proposal produces identical byte code.

Comment: There really isn't much more to say. The answer is fundamentally, "_That's not allowed because it's not allowed_", hence I don't consider the question to be that good. It's also why I speculated in a comment rather than posting an answer. That said, the feature request you found and linked to is interesting and the extra information you provided can be helpful to others, if not the OP.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is not something that JetBrains have specifically prevented; it's just that it would need something added to the language spec, compiler, etc., and they haven't done so.  (Note that there's no separate `?` operator; `?.` is a single operator in its own right, so you can't just apply `?` to `[`.)